# Changing OS JAVA system properties

Tags: java

I am currently trying to run an app using a binary. The command errors out saying

```
# sh target/appassembler/bin/app --id default
This tool must be launched with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Using a Java command and setting the system property it does work

```
# java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar target/update-center2-*-SNAPSHOT-bin/update-center2-*-SNAPSHOT.jar --id default
// Some arbitrary output from the app
```

But I need to run the app as a binary. I understand that the app expects `file.encoding=UTF-8`.Looking at the JAVA system properties on my OS

```
# java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

I can clearly see that the issue is with the system properties. My question is how can I change it in the OS/JAVA settings?

Comment: You could create a (forwarding) main with `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`. Of course the OS will keep its own encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the simplest is to set the `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable as explained